# UITool bar button with image and dynamic text "Below" it

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I want to implement a Button on the `UIToolbar`  with "*Image*" On Top and Text below it as shown below.

[image]

I have used the following code:

```
UIButton* customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setTitle:@"Categorie" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem* cataBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];initWithCustomView:customButton];
cataBtn
```

But it shows the result as follows:

[image]

How should i customize it in such a way that the Image is On top and Text Below it ?

I dont want to  use a single image with both picture and text, since the text is a dynamically changing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the edge insets

```
customButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -60, -30, 0);
customButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-15, 0 , 0, 0); // give some space for text
```

Comment: it is ok but another problem is that the popOver which was invoked earlier fails to display now. Any workaround for this ?  [searchpopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

Comment: setting the contentEdgeInsets should not affect the popover in anyway. update your question with the popovercontroller code.

Comment: yeah u r right the problem was that the popOver controller does not get the UIBarButtonItem. Any way i had solved it as follows. May be some one will need it later===>   NSArray *toolBarItems = [toolbarObj items];[searchpopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[toolBarItems objectAtIndex:2] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];